# Which Hosting Plan Should I use for this Web Application

Tags: web-hosting, php, web-development, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

I am developing a Web Application [PHP & MySQL] which is basically a rating website ( a social bookmarking site ). There are many tables in the Database like: Users, Notifications, Posts, Following and more.

Which Hosting Plan should I use to host it : Shared or VPS. And yes, I don't think it needs a dedicated web server. If traffic grows, I will upgrade the plan to dedicated.

One more thing: I am not using any CMS or Framework. I am writing the code myself and I will also try to make the website faster ( and lighter on the server ) by hosting CSS and JS files in DropBox. I will buy the hosting plan from Hostgator (India) : is it good or should I go with another company?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You answered your question by yourself: upgrade the hosting-plan when it becomes necessary!

Start as low as you can (with having costs between $5 to $10/month, excl. domains) and update the contract if it becomes necessary. Try to find a hoster, who does all the data migration from shared hosting to managed hosting to a dedicated server without to many extra costs and a fast tariff-updating procedure.